Push footer to extreme bottom with 0 margin
I am using fancyhdr package and the following statement to print a footer :
\fancyfoot[LE]{\hspace*{-1.75cm}\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}ebook for John E Mark - Do not redistribute}

I need this footer text to be on the extreme bottom left corner of the page. I am able to shift it to the left but not able to shift it to the bottom. Tried multiple things but it is not moving vertically.
Any idea what can be done?
Edit:
Here is the MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\hspace*{-1.75cm}\vspace*{-1cm}ebook for John E Mark - Do not redistribute}
\begin{document}
The following is random text
 \pagebreak
 
The following is random text 
 
\end{document}



Can you provide code we can compile? Help preparing a minimal working example to assist people helping you: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228. But try \vspace*. This is not the best way to do this, though. I would instead include this independently of the page layout using a hook at shipout to add it to the page background/foreground.

Do you want it on every page?

I want it on every alternate page. That's why I tried to use [LE] instead of [RO, LE].

Assuming you want this on every page, I would place it using the shipout/background hook. If you have some other background picture or colour, use shipout/foreground instead. For every odd or every even page, test the shipout count during shipout.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
% still use fancyhdr if you want custom haders/footers in the standard places
% \usepackage{fancyhdr}
% \pagestyle{fancy}
% \fancyhf{}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}[JEM]
{%
  \ifodd\ReadonlyShipoutCounter\relax\else
    \put (\fboxsep,\dimexpr\fboxsep-\paperheight) {ebook for John E. Mark --- Do not redistribute}%
  \fi
}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% for dummy text - not in your real document!
\begin{document}
The following is random text
\kant[1-20]
\end{document}

[Image removed because I don't know how to get an image of an even page right now.]
If you want it only for a single page, use \AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put ...} instead.

Yes, this works but how to I put it only on alternate pages like \fancyfoot[LE] was doing. Thx.

@Priyshrm Apologies. I missed that even though I read it. See edited answer above. Sorry no visuals. Okular-on-X has a bug and I have an alternative method with some limitations. I could provide an image of page 1, but page 2 is trickier.

thank you very much!!

With geometry package you can do the following
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE]{ebook for John E Mark - Do not redistribute}

\usepackage{geometry}
\makeatletter
\fancyfootoffset{\Gm@rmargin}
\setlength{\footskip}{\Gm@bmargin}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
The following is random text
 \pagebreak
 
The following is random text
\end{document}

\fancyfootoffset allows to specify an optional argument, so in case you have another footer for odd pages, you could add
\fancyfoot[LE]{ebook for John E Mark - Do not redistribute}
\fancyfoot[LO]{odd footer}

\makeatletter
\fancyfootoffset[LE]{\dimexpr\Gm@rmargin}
\fancyfootoffset[LO]{\dimexpr\Gm@lmargin}
\makeatother


